# Respoinse Assertions in JMeter with Jenkins - never showing a failure

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

looking for a little guidance.

I have a basic JMeter test plan setup to load a page.  I've added a couple of assertions in to check that text on screen is displayed (used response assertions for these.)  I ran the plan using the JMeter GUI and deliberately caused the assertion to fail - there was a 15% error rate - so this was good.

I then tried to run the same plan in Jenkins using the Performance Plugin (and have updated to the latest version) however the test always returns as passed.  I have confirmed (via the console output) that the 15% error has still been seen.

The job is currently configured with a failed % range of 0.0 to 0.0 and "Use Error thresholds on single build: " is set to 0 for failed and for unstable.

I think I am missing something here - are any jmeter/jenkins experts able to give me a few pointers?

Comment: did you specify the path to .jtl files correctly in the Report files input? you should run the test by installing new build into Jenkins, which eventually triggers the JMeter test using jmeter.bat file (should run the test in non-GUI mode)

Answer (score 0):

**Jenkins Configuration**:

1. Add a new report selecting the appropriate parser for your reports (JMeter, JUnit)
2. Configure the search pattern to select the files to be parsed by the Performance plugin. Depending on the parser there is a default pattern to be used if you leave the input box blank.
3. You can configure the error percentage thresholds which would make the project unstable or failed or leave them blank to disable the feature.

**Performance Plugin usage**:

4. As soon as you have configured Jenkins and launched a first build, you'll notice that a new entry is appearing in the left summary : Performance trend.
5. If you just have one report file, the graph of this reports will appear on the main page.
6. If you have more of one report file, you must click on "Performance Trend" and the graphs will appear

try the following links:

1. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin
2. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins