# JMeter - Maven build should fail if JMeter throughput is under x or error-percentage over y%

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter

I'm using JMeter with Jenkins and I want my Maven-Build to fail, if my throughput is too low (for example lower than 15 requests/s) or if my error-percentage is too high (for example more than 1%). In other cases it should be successful. I could not find out how to configure it like that. Can you help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I finally found this question: [Respoinse Assertions in JMeter with Jenkins - never showing a failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717137/respoinse-assertions-in-jmeter-with-jenkins-never-showing-a-failure)

I will try this, but if you have additional information or hints, please post them.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider running JMeter via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a part of your Jenkins build as an alternative solution (or in addition) to performance plugin thresholds.

Taurus naturally supports JMeter .jmx test scripts and it comes with handy and flexible [Pass/Fail Criteria](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) where you can set multiple thresholds.

In case of fail criteria being met Taurus will automatically fail the test (and stop it as an option) and return non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) so Jenkins will know that the build has failed.

See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) guide for more details.